# Subquery resulting duplicates

Tags: sql, subquery

Sorry for the lengthy query below, with how the database is organized and my little SQL knowledge, it is the only way I can get it to play nice. So the database has a field `TicketDate` in which I need the MAX value of. However, it is defined as a char(8) variable instead of datetime. So getting the MAX isn't as easy as `MAX(TicketDate as DATETIME)`, it doesn't actually result with the max date.

**The query works on its own:**

```
--***SUB QUERY (TimeTicketDet)
        SELECT DISTINCT
            cast(TicketDate as DATE) as MAXtt,
            tt.JobNo
        FROM TimeTicketDet as tt

        ORDER BY
            cast(TicketDate as DATE) DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS
```

However when added into the main query, I get duplicate rows for each TimeTicketEntry. The query works fine without the last subquery (no duplicates) `--***SUB QUERY (TimeTicketDet)`. JobNo is the unique identifier for the TimeTicketDet table and was used as the link.

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME
DECLARE @90daysago DATETIME

SET @now = GETDATE()
SET @90daysago = DATEADD(day, -90, @now)


SELECT
    o.PartNo,
    o.JobNo,
    ord.DateEnt,
    por.MAXPONum,
    po.DateEnt,
    tt.MAXtt,
    r.ReceiveDate,

            CASE
            WHEN po.DateEnt >= r.ReceiveDate AND po.DateEnt >= tt.MAXtt THEN cast(po.DateEnt as DATE)
            WHEN r.ReceiveDate >= po.DateEnt AND r.ReceiveDate >= tt.MAXtt THEN cast(r.ReceiveDate as DATE)
            WHEN tt.MAXtt >= po.DateEnt AND tt.MAXtt >= r.ReceiveDate THEN cast(tt.MAXtt as DATE)
            ELSE po.DateEnt
            END AS MostRecentDate,

    POProrate.TotalCost,
    WIPProrate.WIPProrateCost,
    (POProrate.TotalCost+WIPProrate.WIPProrateCost) as ProratedCost,
    (ROUND(cast((o.QtyToMake - o.QtyShipped2Stock) as FLOAT)/o.QtyToMake,3))*(POProrate.TotalCost+WIPProrate.WIPProrateCost) as TotalProratedCost

FROM
--***MAIN QUERY (OrderDet)***
    OrderDet as o

--***SUB QUERY (Order)***
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                cast(DateEnt as DATE) as DateEnt,
                OrderNo
            FROM
                Orders
        ) ord
        ON ord.OrderNo = o.OrderNo


--***SUB QUERY (POReleases)***
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                MAX(PONum) as MAXPONum,
                JobNo
            FROM
                POReleases
            GROUP BY
                JobNo
        ) por
        ON por.JobNo = o.JobNo

--***SUB QUERY (PO)***
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                PONum,
                cast(DateEnt as DATE) as DateEnt
            FROM
                PO
        ) po
        ON po.PONum = por.MAXPONum

--***SUB QUERY (TimeTicketDet)
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
            cast(TicketDate as DATE) as MAXtt,
            tt.JobNo
        FROM TimeTicketDet as tt

        ORDER BY
            cast(TicketDate as DATE) DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS
        ) tt
        ON tt.JobNo = o.JobNo

--***SUB QUERY (Receiver)
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                rd.JobNo,
                cast(MAX(r.ReceiveDate) as DATE) as ReceiveDate
            FROM
                Receiver as r
            INNER JOIN
                ReceiverDet as rd ON r.PONum = rd.PONum
            GROUP BY
                rd.JobNo

        ) r
        ON r.JobNo = o.JobNo

--***SUB QUERY (POProrate)***
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                j.JobNo,
                SUM(j.TotalCost) as TotalCost

            FROM
                (   
                    SELECT
                            por.JobNo,
                    CASE
                        WHEN pod.Unit = 'LOT' THEN SUM(pod.UnitCost*1)
                        ELSE SUM(por.Qty*pod.UnitCost)
                    END as TotalCost
                    FROM
                        PODet as pod
                    INNER JOIN
                        POReleases as por ON pod.PONum = por.PONum and pod.partno=por.partno
                    GROUP BY por.JobNo, pod.Unit

                ) j

            GROUP BY j.JobNo
        ) POProrate
        ON o.JobNo = POProrate.JobNo

--***SUB QUERY (WIPProrate)***
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                j.JobNo,
                SUM(j.ProratedCost) as WIPProrateCost

            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        tt.StepNo,
                        tt.JobNo,
                        tt.ActualPayRate,
                        tt.BurdenRate,
                        tt.CycleTime,
                        tt.SetupTime,
                        tt.CycleTime + tt.SetupTime as TotalTime,
                        (tt.CycleTime + tt.SetupTime) * tt.ActualPayRate as LaborCost,
                        (tt.CycleTime + tt.SetupTime) * tt.BurdenRate as BurdenCost,
                        ((tt.CycleTime + tt.SetupTime) * tt.ActualPayRate) + ((tt.CycleTime + tt.SetupTime) * tt.BurdenRate) as ProratedCost
                    FROM
                        TimeTicketDet as tt
                ) j

            GROUP BY j.JobNo
        ) WIPProrate
        ON WIPProrate.JobNo = o.JobNo

WHERE
    o.Status = 'Open'
    AND o.JobNo <> ''
    AND ord.DateEnt <= @90daysago
    AND po.DateEnt <= @90daysago
    AND tt.MAXtt <= @90daysago
    AND r.ReceiveDate <= @90daysago
```

**The goal of the query is find all relevant dates, <=90 days old, add to the list. All I am missing is the last date, which would pull the correct TicketDate from the TimeTicketDet table and join it on JobNo.**

I am happy to add or take away any information requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your subquery to:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(TicketDate as DATE)) as MaxTT,
       JobNo
FROM TimeTicketDet as tt
GROUP BY JobNo
```

I assume your current query must be returning multiple `MaxTT` dates for any given `JobNo`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought I had tried that and it was not actually giving me the MAX TicketDate, however I have spot checked about 5 and it seems to be returning the correct information. I will check about 20 more and mark this as answered if everything checks out!

Comment: @RBCKyleBullard YW, and by the way, the rest of your query looks pretty good.  The only thing you might change is to move your final `WHERE/AND` filters into their subqueries wherever possible.  The optimizer should be smart enough to execute the query that way, but it probably won't be.  Which means you would pull the entire table and then filter it, instead of pulling the filtered result set from the start.